# Ubuntu 12.04 disk installs LTS on desktop?? wrong display drivers

Tags: display, resolution

I used the same 12.04 install disk to install on two desktop machines.  One worked correctly and easily recognized the Dell 2210 display.  The other loaded an LTS (laptop??) version that has a display driver that insists it's on a laptop with all the wrong resolution options.  Reloaded again and couldn't find any way to force loading the desktop version.  how do I fix this?

Comment: Are these identical desktops? What type of graphics device is it using?

Comment: no, quite different.  Both came to me running CentOS.  The problem machine is using VESA: MACH64GM driver. The video is on the motherboard. It's got dual AMD 64's. can't find the motherboard ID.  Any idea why 12.04 insists it's a laptop and won't let me change it??

Comment: I just installed 12.04 and you might want to try installing with "nomodeset" option. I was having some graphics issues and this helped me get a generic install done and from there I was able to install proprietary drivers. Using nomodeset seems to help with a variety of graphical issues even if it possibly isnt the most elegant solution to your issue. You should be able to google how to do so but I will try to clarify if you cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

LTS stands for Long Term Support. Ubuntu 12.04 is a LTS release (meaning: it would have longer support and other candies) and it does not mean that you'll get laptop display drivers installed.
If your current display driver isn't working properly (assuming it's the default, open source version for graphic card by NVidia or ATI/AMD), you can try installing the proprietary drivers, by running the program "gtk-jockey".

Comment: maybe I'm not clear.  I used the same disk to install 12.04 on two desktop machines.  On restart, one comes up correctly and the "Displays" settings dialog recognizes the Dell 2210.  The other machine comes up with a completely different "Displays" dialog saying it thinks it's a laptop with no way to tell it it's not and no way to select a correct screen resolution.

Comment: Ok, try installing the additional drivers for a graphic card in this computer - it may solve the issue (the application to run is "Additional Drivers").

Comment: it says "No proprietary drivers are installed on this system".

Comment: Do you have option to install any?
Do you know what graphic card you have on this system?